# Error running app after upgrading to Ionic RC4

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, ionic2, angular2-aot

I'm having a hard time running my app after upgrading from Ionic rc3 to rc4.

When I build the app by running `ionic-app-scripts build --prod` it compiles fine without any errors.

But when I run the app on my iPhone, I get a blank screen and the following error in the Safari Console:

```
Error: Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot set property 'sources' of undefined
at /Users/andreas/IdeaProjects/project/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/webpack/loader-impl.js:35:37
```

It seemed to be related to the sourcemap generation, so I tried turning it off, but that didn't help. `ionic-app-scripts build --prod --generateSourceMap=false`

I then create a blank app and it worked just fine. So there seems to be a problem with my app specifically. However, I have no idea where I have to start debugging this error. I already tried to adjust the file where I got the error, but that also didn't help (and it wouldn't be a clean solution either).

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I didn't see the breaking changes in the ionic-app-scripts. I had to alter the tsconfig.json, now I get a new error:

`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./app.module.ngfactory"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `ionic-app-scripts` is having issues with Typescript 2.1 and above. If you started building your app before rc2, you will have Typescript version `"^2.0.3"` in your `package.json`. Simply change it to `"2.0.x"` and run `npm i`.